# I got confuse when try to calculate Expectation value with Python (with and without replacement)!

Tags: probability, python

Sorry if my question is more relate to programing than Math!

> A committee of four people is drawn at random from a set of six men and three women. Suppose we are concerned that there may be quite a gender imbalance in the membership of the committee. Toward that end, let $M$ and $W$ denote the numbers of men and women in our committee, and let
> the difference be $D = M − W$. Let’s find $E(D)$.

How I calculate:

$D = \{-2,0,2,4\}, D = -2$ means there are $1$ man and $3$ women.

$$E(D) = -2 \times P(D = -2) + 0 + 2 \times P(D = 2) + 4 \times P(D = -4)$$

**Without Replacement**

$P(D = -2) = \frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{9}{4}}$ and get result $E(D) = \frac{4}{3}$ ~ 1.3333

**With Replacement**
I use the formula in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets

$P(D = -2) = \frac{6 \times \binom{3 + 3 -1}{3}}{\binom{9 + 4 -1}{4}}$ and get result $E(D) = \frac{16}{11}\sim1.4545$

But when I Try to check with Python, both will have almost the same results $1,33$.

**My method:**
I created a list in which has numbers from 1 to 9. Numbers <= 6 refer to Men, otherwise are women.
I will loop `n` times, each time I generate a sample and calculate $D$ and add to `total`. Finally, find the mean `total / n`.

```
import random 
import numpy as np
pop = []
for i in range(1,10):
    pop.append(i)

n = 300000
total = 0
for _ in range(n):
    a = np.array(np.random.choice(pop, 4)) #with replacemant
    #a = np.array(random.sample(pop, k=4)) #without replacement
    total += sum(a <= 6) - sum(a > 6)
print('Result',total/n)
```

Answer (score 1):

$$E[D]=E[M-W]=E[M]-E[W]=4\cdot \frac{6}{9}-4\cdot\frac{3}{9}=\frac{4}{3}$$

There was never any need to calculate $\Pr(D=-2)$ or any of the others.  You could have approached purely by linearity of expectation.

$M$ could be thought of as $M_1+M_2+M_3+M_4$ where $M_i$ is the indicator random variable corresponding to if the $i$'th person selected was male or not.  This was how I was able to so quickly say that $E[M]=4\cdot \frac{6}{9}$.  In both the with replacement and without replacement scenarios, $\Pr(M_i=1)=\frac{6}{9}$ seen immediately by noting that each person is just as likely as each other person to have been the $i$'th person selected... the dependence of the events is completely irrelevant and can be ignored when approaching with linearity of expectation.  Both posed problems have an answer of $\frac{4}{3}$

The punchline is going to be in the end... that your $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ arrangements counted with stars and bars are **not** going to be equally likely scenarios.  That is the source of your error.  The correct value for with replacement should have had a denominator of $9^4$ and for $D=-2$ (*one man three women*) would have had a numerator of $\binom{4}{1}\cdot 6^1\cdot 3^3$, corresponding to picking which position in the sequence the male was picked, which male it was in that position, and which female(s) they were in those positions.  Note also that for the with replacement problem if you were to insist on approaching the hard and tedious long way, there also exists the possibility of $D=-4$.

Comment: (+1) for parts on sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

How does sampling *with* replacement make any practical
sense when choosing a committee? (I ignore
computations that involve sampling with replacement.)

I agree with
your answer $E(D) = 1.3333.$

Because you're interested in verification via
simulation, I simulated this in R, using `1`'s
for the men, `-1`'s for the women. (The `sample` procedure in R samples without replacement by default, treating the nine elements of `mem`
as distinct; for example, it will never pick
four `-1`'s.)

I get the approximation
$E(D)=1.3322 \pm 0.0030.$ [With a million iterations
one can expect 2 or 3 place accuracy.]

```
set.seed(1234)
mem = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)
d = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(mem, 4)))
mean(d)
[1] 1.332196     # aprx E(D)
2*sd(d)/1000
[1] 0.002979235  # 95% margin of sim error
table(d)/10^6
d
       -2        0        2        4 
 0.047345 0.358031 0.475805 0.118819
```

*Notes:* (1) Also, your combinatorial value for $P(D=-2) = 0.0476,$
compared with simulated value $0.0473,$ which agrees within the margin of simulation error.

(2) I don't use Python enough to feel
competent commenting on your program.

Comment: Re: "*I don't use Python enough to feel competent commenting on your program*"  I can comment, the OP's code is just fine and does as advertised (*though could be cleaned a bit in terms of showing the results for both problems without needing to modify the code*).  Your R code does raise a valid point though that the OP should take note on, for sharing simulated results it is very helpful to set the random seed to ensure others get the same results.  That can be done in python using `random.seed(42)` or replacing whatever else arbitrary value rather than 42 you like in there.

Comment: Uncomment and unexplained code in any language can be difficult // And what about the nonsense about sampling with replacement? Do 'doubly selected members' get two votes?